# Event sender address

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

In web3JS, when I get past events, I can see the event and the tx hash, I can then do `getTransaction` on the corresponding tx hash and then see the sender address, but this is **wasteful** as I have to **iterate** over all the events and compare it with a desired address (say browser client address).

Is it possible through web3js to access who **triggered** the event in the **filtering** itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `indexed` keyword used in `Events`.

This allows searching and filtering on events.

See: [What does the indexed keyword do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8658/what-does-the-indexed-keyword-do)

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if I were able to find that without adding another byte32 to every event emitted, but I guess that'll do, thanks :)